How can I open an .xlsx file from a shared OneDrive's link into R?
I'm working remotely and having an issue about a downloaded .xlsx file from a OneDrive's colleague. I was tired to download the .xlsx file daily from his OneDrive so I tried a code to get around this waste of time.
My code:
url <- "https://link_to_the_xlsx_file" # sorry the data is confidential

response <- GET(url, write_disk("TEST_TEL.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE))


I think this code works since I've the .xlsx file in my environment with "167KB". But when I tried to open into R I've got this message:

" 'Is this a valid Excel file?zip file 'C:\Users\User\Documents\TEST_TEL.xlsx' cannot be opened' "

I tried to open the file directly but I've got a similar message:
"Excel cannot open the file 'TEST_TEL.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has nos been corrupted or that the file extension matches the format of the file"
Then, I tried to go into Excel and open this specific file from Excel. Finally it works but it didn't resolve my issue. When I tried to re-open the file into R I got the same error message. Any ideas to figure out this issue please?
Edit:


How was this link generated? Does it work as a direct download  link when you open it in  incognito window (i.e in a browser sessioon where you are not logged in to OneDrive)? What to you get for GET() response? Is status OK (200) and does content type make sense or it's something like text/html? I somehow doubt that it's a xslx you downloaded,  probably a html of online editor/viewer or an html with some error message (you could check by opening it in a text editor).

The link was generated by : "Share" --> "Copy the link to this workbook".
I tried to copy + paste the link into Tor and it worked. I checked the status and content, it seems ok (please see my edit in my post). You got a point, effectively when I opened the file in a text editor the "DOCTYPE" is html... Do you have a solution?

By "it worked", you mean it started downlowidng or it was opened in online Excel? You could try setting / changing url's query part to ?download=1, e.g. if your link is something like org-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/me/...prblnvQ?e=k5983N, change it to org-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/me/...prblnvQ?download=1

Sorry, I meant it was opened in online Excel. I added "download=1" but still got the same error message.
